# about OS error cannot find source in Python

Tags: python, wordcloud2

I am a Korean who just started learning python now. I was doing wordcloud with Korean text. I think I did everything I was taught. But I got this error that I cannot resolve. please help me.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from collections import Counter
from konlpy.tag import Okt
```

this is the input

```
text=''
with open("./res/대한민국헌법.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:

text = f.read()

nlp =Okt()
nouns =nlp.nouns(text)
# print(nouns)
# print("-" * 30)

words=[]
for n in nouns:
    if len(n) >1:
        words.append(n)
# print(words)
print("-" * 30)

#Counter 객체를 통해 리스트 원소들의 빈도수 계산
count =Counter(words)

most=count.most_common(100)
# print(most)
print("-" * 30)

tags={}
for t in most:
    n, c= t
    tags[n]=c

print(tags)

wc= WordCloud(font_path="NanumGothic", width=1200, height=800,
                scale=2.0, max_font_size=250)

wc.generate_from_frequencies(tags) # <- this is where I got the error from
wc.to_file("대한민국헌법-주요단어.png")
```

This is the output

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\hyeokjun\01-파이썬기초, 데이터
>   시각화\09-데이터시각화
>   -가로막대+파이+산점도그래프+워드클라우드\파이썬09강\파이썬09강\section09\01.numeric.py", line 40, in 
>       wc.generate_from_frequencies(tags)   File "C:\Users\newjh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py",
>   line 496, in generate_from_frequencies
>       font = ImageFont.truetype(self.font_path, font_size)   File "C:\Users\newjh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py",
>   line 648, in truetype
>       return freetype(font)   File "C:\Users\newjh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py",
>   line 645, in freetype
>       return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)   File
>   "C:\Users\newjh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py",
>   line 194, in **init**
>       font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine=layout_engine OSError: cannot open resource [Finished in 5.9s]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems the font cannot be retrieved. 
Try copying the font "NanumGothic" into your project folder or update the `font_path="NanumGothic"` in the following line to point to the correct font file:

```
wc= WordCloud(font_path="/path/to/fontfile", width=1200, height=800,
                scale=2.0, max_font_size=250)
```

Comment: Thanks man. I moved the font file and It worked:)

Comment: Glad that worked!